# Insufficient privilege for operation like Get-AzureADApplication and Set-AzureADApplication

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I would like to automate deployment and it requires to update settings for Azure AD Application registration.

So far I am able to :

- create an Azure AD Appregistration and Service Principal with certificate (thx MS documentation)
- then use command Connect-AzureAD with previous service Principal with its certificate
- use command like Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555
- In previous bullet ObjectId 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 match with application i created on first bullet

However i am unable to execute command like:

- Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$aADApplicationame'"
- and $aADApplicationame matches with application created previously
- Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $aADApplication.ObjectId -ReplyUrls $ReplyUrls
- Get-AzADServicePrincipal

I get following error message

> Set-AzureADApplication : Error occurred while executing SetApplication
> Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
> Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Based on my research, i set up some API permissions as follow:
[image]

Unfortunately no luck and still get insufficient privilege although all permissions were granted.
Do you know if I miss something ? Is there any specific permissions i should add to make it works ?
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by another reply, you could give the `Global Administrator` role to the service principal, it is correct, but the permission of `Global Administrator` is too large in this case, it may cause some security issues.

In this case, the commands `Get-AzureADApplication` and `Set-AzureADApplication` you used essentially call the Azure AD Graph API, so to solve the issue, a better solution is to add the permission of Azure AD Graph API, please follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the `API permissions` of your AD App -> select `Azure Active Directory Graph`(**not `Microsoft Graph`**).

[image]

2.Select `Application permissions`(**not `Delegated permissions`**) -> `Application.ReadWrite.All` -> click `Add permissions`.

[image]

3.At last, click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button.

[image]

After a while, try the commands again, it will work fine.

**Update:**

After I check the doc, I find there are already some new commands released by MS which call the Microsoft Graph, haven't seen them before.

e.g. In your case, you can use [`Get-AzureADMSApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadmsapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) instead of `Get-AzureADApplication`.

```
Get-AzureADMSApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'joyttt'"
```

Use [`Set-AzureADMSApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) instead of `Set-AzureADApplication`.

```
Set-AzureADMSApplication -ObjectId <object-id> -Web @{ RedirectUris = "https://mynewapp.contoso.com/" }
```

For `Get-AzADServicePrincipal`, there is no equivalent currently, there should be one in the future. When using the commands above, the permissions of Microsoft Graph will work, no need to use Azure AD Graph, but you should use `Application permission`, not `Delegated permission` (you used the `Delegated permission` in your question.)

Comment: Hi Joy Wang. I appreciated your help and your screenshot help me a lot to make it works. However I noticed that your method use legacy Azure API which is is deprecated (I got a warning on screen) and MS highly recommends to move to Graph API instead. Do you have a solution with Graph API ? I tested AD App -> select Microsoft Graph (and not Azure Active Directory Graph) > Application permissions(not Delegated permissions) -> Application.ReadWrite.All -> click Add permissions. But i still get forbidden access. Strange isn't it ?

Comment: @terry It is not strange, because the command calls azure ad graph, not microsoft graph. Don’t worry about that, MS just will not add new feature to aad graph, you can still use it. In the future, there maybe new command which calls MS graph, but now, it is the best solution, just use it.

Comment: Perfect thanks for your quick feedback :) I will adopt AzureAD graph as you suggested. It works like a charm.

Comment: @terry Looks there are already some new commands as I mentioned, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this issue because Powershell cmdlet works differently than compared to MS Graph. Instead of permissions, Powershell require roles to do this operations. Please add Global Administrator role to your service principle and then try the `Connect-AzureAD` so that, the issue will be fixed.

For more details, you may refer to [Assigning administrator roles in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles).

Comment: Hi Hari, Thx for your answer. Your solution should work but giving Global administrator is too much in my context.

Comment: Hi @terry, You can also give minimum permission like Application Administrator instead of Global Administrator.It is better to assign role than permission because AAD Graph is Deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue, make sure are doing below two things:

1. Set Run as account for azure automation account
2. In newly created app registration for azure automation account after setting Run as account, make sure you add Cloud application administrator role explicitly.
3. Add API permission for Application.ReadWrite.All (Microsoft graph)

In my case the app registration was showing cloud application administrator role under Roles and Administrator screen, which I thought gives the new app registration required permission but that was not the case. PowerShell script only worked after we assigned the cloud application administrator role explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning thanks for previous posts it gave a lot of inspiration according topic. Problem occurred in our case at automated bicep mechanism that is supposed to add API permissions for Microsoft Graph.

**Error:** Authorization_RequestDenied

**Solution**:
We needed to give Enterprise Application running mechanism Microsoft Graph (not Azure Active Directory Graph it will be deprecated) Application permissions:

- Application.ReadWrite.All
- AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All
- Directory.ReadWrite.All